# Is it possible to rotate a 128-bit value in Altivec?

Tags: c, rotation, intrinsics, powerpc, altivec

I'm trying to port some ARM NEON code to AltiVec. Our NEON code has two LOAD's, one ROT, one XOR and a STORE so it seems like a simple test case. According to IBM's [`vec_rl`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGH2K_13.1.2/com.ibm.xlc131.aix.doc/compiler_ref/vec_rl.html) documentation:

> Each element of the result is obtained by rotating the corresponding element of a left by the number of bits specified by the corresponding element of b.

The docs go on to say `vector unsigned int` is the largest data type unless `-qarch=power8`, in which case `vector unsigned long long` applies.

I'd like to perform a 128-bit rotate, and not 32-bit or 64-bit rotation of individual elements. The bit positions are 19, 31, 67, 97, and 109. They are not byte aligned. (The constants arise from the [ARIA block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARIA_(cipher))).

Are 4x32 and 2x64 the largest AltiVec data arrangements? Is it possible to rotate a 128-bit value in Altivec?

If the packed rotate is the only operation available, then is it a best practice to do the bit twiddling in C or in AltiVec?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a rotate by a multiple of 8 bits using `vsld` (`vec_sld`), then to handle any remaining rotation of < 8 bits you'll probably need to use `vsl` + `vsr` + `vsel` (`vec_sll` + `vec_srl` + `vec_sel`).

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'm having trouble finding information on `vec_sll` and `vec_srl`. They are not documented at IBM's [Vector built-in functions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGH2K_13.1.2/com.ibm.xlc131.aix.doc/compiler_ref/vec_intrin_cpp.html). Would you be able to share more information?

Comment: On a mobile device just now, but Google "AltiVec PIM" and you should see a PDF in the top few hits which documents all the intrinsics etc. The companion manual is "AltiVec PEM" which documents the actual instructions.

Comment: Note: your question is tagged `PowerPC` - are you actually working with PowerPC/AltiiVec or is it IBM POWER/VMX (similar but different).

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'm working on [GCC112 from the compile farm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/CompileFarm), which is described as IBM POWER8.

Comment: Right, but what hardware platform are you targeting ? POWER or PowerPC ?

Comment: Thanks again Paul. The command line I am using is `/opt/cfarm/gcc-latest/bin/g++ -g3 -O1 -m64 -maltivec -mabi=altivec -mcrypto -pthread -c rijndael-simd.cpp` (where rijndael is a similar problem). My apologies if I should be further along. I have not found a good article or tutorial explaining things, so I'm cobbling things together. As I understand things, both AltiVec and IBM offer the extensions under different trade names. They should be the same instructions. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: OK - well if you're targeting PowerPC/AltiVec then those 128 bit shift intrinsics should be available in altivec.h. Did you find the AltiVec PIM PDF ?