# Double-word vector rotates on old Altivec's without 64-bit data type

Tags: c++, 64-bit, intrinsics, powerpc, altivec

This is related to Power4 and [lack of `vector long long`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47771721/608639). On Power7 and Power8 we can perform:

```cxx
typedef __vector unsigned long long uint64x2_p;
...

uint64x2_p val = {...};
uint64x2_p res = vec_rl(val, val, bits);
```

I need to find a workaround for the missing 64-bit vector type and rotate on Power4. I think there are two strategies. First, rotate in C/C++ or; second, use 32-bit vector types. I'm guessing (2) is the faster strategy given the data is in a vector register.

I feel like this problem was solved long ago since there's nothing special about a double-word rotate. Unfortunately search is not returning useful hits: ["power4" "doubleword" rotate](http://www.google.com/search?q="power4"+"doubleword"+rotate).

I think I have the basic algorithm that consists of three LOAD's, two SHIFT's, two PERM's and an OR. But I'm not sure if there's a better approach.

How do I perform a 64-bit rotate when working on Power4, which lacks the double-word rotate?

---

```cxx
typedef __vector unsigned int uint32x4_p;

template <unsigned int R>
inline uint32x4_p VecRotateLeft64(const uint32x4_p val)
{
    enum {LSHIFT = R%32};
    enum {RSHIFT = 32 - (R%32)};
    enum {PERMUTE = R > 32};

    const uint32x4_p lbits = {LSHIFT,LSHIFT,LSHIFT,LSHIFT};
    uint32x4_p left(vec_sl(val, lbits));

    const uint32x4_p rbits = {RSHIFT,RSHIFT,RSHIFT,RSHIFT};
    uint32x4_p right(vec_sr(val, rbits));

    const uint8x16_p mask = {4,5,6,7, 0,1,2,3, 12,13,14,15, 8,9,10,11};
    right = vec_perm(right, right, mask);
    uint32x4_p result = vec_or(left, right);

    // Permute left and right parts of 64-bit word as needed
    if (PERMUTE)
        result = vec_perm(result, result, mask);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @PaulR - I think this is my last question related to the old Altivec machines. This particular problem has held up porting of some algorithms from Power7 back to Power4 for us. It has been a wart on my PowerMac testing for months.

Comment: I think it's going to be pretty messy and long-winded with 32 bit shifts/masks/permutes/etc - you might be able to do something with vec_sll/vec_sllo, otherwise it's going to be scalar code. (See also [this question re 128 bit rotates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46016023/253056)).

Comment: A bit of testing on godbolt.org suggests that gcc prefers scalar code for this in power4.

Comment: Do you need this in the middle of stuff that does vectorize well?  If not, 64-bit scalar rotate instructions are probably very good, assuming PowerPC has that.  But if the inputs and output are already in vector registers, then IDK how much it sucks to unpack / repack.  It's probably not bad; it's only two elements, so unless the latency is very high it might be ok.